# Fully integrated H-bridge motor driver IC VS external FETs

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, dc-motor, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I'm designing a new motor driver for a DC motor which has starting peak current of 30A and 28Volts power supply. Previous engineer used an integrated motor driver IC solution (VNH3SP30-E) that has a MOSFET (Full H-bridge) inside an IC. There are so many customer complaints that it is blowing up in the field. When I look at the IC there is not good separation and everything things runs off the high power line. I don't know what is the advantage of using a integrated driver solution over original MOSFET/IGBT approach. I personally think having external FETs would be a safer approach. Has any one used the integrated solutions before ? if yes, is it better than original power electronics. I'm trying to see which is a better approach.

Comment: That part was probably picked by an engineer that did not have a power background. 36V and 30A is to close to the load to be safe. Any large transient on the power supply would probably blow it. Pick a part where your load is consiveritive not the rating of the chip. You do not state what the mechanical load is but if it has a flywheel  effect a lot of energy will be coming at the IC.

Comment: Yes, the previous engineer is not a power electronics guy. He didn't add any filtering on main supply feeding the IC to suppress any power supply transients. There is 650in-lb of torque from load and huge back emf of 90V due to water pressure. He tried to observe the back emf in the system through diodes and resistor combination. Initially the IC blew up because of this. Also, during starting the torque is huge and peak current reaches above 30Amps. I see in the datasheet of VNH3SP30, it has linear current limiter which would limit the current and avoid damaging the FETS in the IC.

Comment: Without a schematic and layout, among other specs, we are unable to compare to "original"; voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying a fully integrated bridge assembly such as the BTS7960, available for less then $10.00 Delivered. It should do a good job for you and yes it is a bit of an overkill but it is also cost effective. Test it in your lab and be sure it will do what you want. If it does then you can get the individual parts and build it on your PCB. I prefer integrated solutions because a lot of the grunt work of the design is taken care of such as shoot through, thermal protections, overcurrent protection, etc.